# Attach entity framework object with no context present?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using EF6.0 & .NET 4.5.
I have a bunch of partials extending my framework objects.

A person has multiple cars. These cars have a model/brand (shared among other cars):

```
table person: id, name, whatever, ..
table car: id, personId, modelId, hasCrashedManyTimes, ..
table model: id, brand, model, hasWheels, hasEngine, ..
```

In my main program I do

```
using(var db = My.EntityContext()) // get connection from pool
{
    var person = new person();
    person.cars.Add(new car("Ford", "Focus"));
    db.persons.Add(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

object 'car' is extended

```
public car(string brand, string model) : this()
{
    using(var db = My.EntityContext()) {
        this.model = db.models.FirstOrDefault(m => m.brand == brand && m.model == model)
        if(this.model == null) this.model = new model() { brand = brand, model = model };
    }
}
```

This works but what i did not expect is that 'model' gets added every time. The model I have searched and applied is not 'attached'.

Does anybody understand what I'm trying to do?
Why is this happening and how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You have two things happening here. First, if you retrieve "model" from the context, like you are in this line:

```
this.model = db.models.FirstOrDefault(m => m.brand == brand && m.model == model)
```

Then the object is automatically attached when it is retrieved by the Entity Framework. If you just create it with:

```
this.model = new model()
```

Then it is not attached by default and you need to call the normal context Add method.

Comment: But with an existing model it's fetched (1st), not created (2th). So if it's attached, why is it still adding a new model (with the same properties) to my database?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I need to stick to the same context. This fixed my problem:

```
using(var db = My.EntityContext()) // get connection from pool
{
    var person = new person();
    person.cars.Add(new car(db, "Ford", "Focus"));
    db.persons.Add(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

public car(Entities db, string brand, string model) : this()
{
    this.model = db.models.FirstOrDefault(m => m.brand == brand && m.model == model)
    if(this.model == null) this.model = new model() { brand = brand, model = model };
}
```